# Days of the week - Error at Saturday

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

```
<? 
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest');
    $day = date('w');
$week_monday = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+'.(1-$day).' days'));
$week_tuesday = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+'.(2-$day).' days'));
$week_wednesday = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+'.(3-$day).' days'));
$week_thursday = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+'.(4-$day).' days'));
$week_friday = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+'.(5-$day).' days'));
$week_saturday = date('d-M-y', strtotime('+'.(6-$day).' days'));
```

The code work fine but I want the `date` from `$week_saturday` to be `date('d-m-Y'` not `date('d-M-y'`. If I put the same as the other on `$week_saturday`, the page does not load. Anyone have a clue about what is going on? Thank you very much. Best regards, Bogdan.

Comment: `$week_saturday = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+'.(7-$day).' days'));` this shows me 13-09-2015 but I need to show 12-09-2015.

Comment: what the actual moto of this code.

Comment: It works just fine for me. Copy paste this code, echoed results, edited to d-m-Y, echoed... all working fine.
Are you not doing anything else with $week_saturday ahead on your copde?

Comment: I use somewhere `'<? print $week_saturday; ?>';` but I also use `'<? print $week_friday; ?>';` and it is working the last one.

Comment: Yes its working fine. Just do what @JulioSoares says.

Comment: @BogdanConstantinescu please mark and up-vote the answer for others help. thanks